# How to unlock a password protected locked Intel SSD?

Tags: ssd

I've got a problem with my Intel X25-M 80GB SSD drive that was in one of my laptops (Lenovo).
Since I've got a few laptops (work and stuff) I didn't touch this laptop a while and I forgot my passwords in this laptop.

I did changed the master password of the SSD and encrypted the data.
I did a huge search in the web and I couldn't found a solution to unlock an SSD that is locked (and his master pass has changed).

Really, I've tried anything (partition magic, ubcd, HDDErase, etc) and I can't remove the lock.
I don't care about the data inside.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Without the password you won't be able to unlock it

Comment: @Ramhound He may not be able to unlock it, but can he erase it to make the disk useable again?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Doubtful.

Comment: i was able to secure erase it with some prog, but it remain locked.

Comment: afaik without the master password the SSD is bricked

Comment: Some manufacturers put the same master password in all of their SSDs. If Intel don't, I think that you are totally screwer. Be very careful with these ATA passwords, they are probably the only ones you absolutely can't bypass.

Answer (score 1):

You're dead out of luck. Your only option now is to install a fresh drive and reinstall the OS from scratch.